# Простейший код в JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть слайдер и три кнопки. По нажатию на кнопку на всей странице меняется бэкграунд.

```
    #btn-1:checked ~ .container-fluid {
        background: #849D8F;
        transition: .5s;
    }
```

Проблема заключается в следующем. В навбаре имеется три раздела меню со своими фоном, чуть более ярким, чем бэкграунд на странице. Каким образом можно реализовать следующее действие: При клике на кнопку btn-2 - цвет бэкграунда желтый, кнопки чуть желтее, btn-3 - цвет бекграунда синий, кнопки чуть синее?

Comment: Самый лучший способ это задать какой нибудь общий родитель обоим элементам и изменять его класс (через JS), в зависимости от выбранного пункта. А у этого самого класса дочерним элементам задавать цвета через CSS (то есть и вашему навбару и всему чему угодно).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Извините за ядрёные цвета =)

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 3px;
  transition: .5s;
}
.container-fluid {
   transition: .5s;
   margin-top: -34px;
}
#btn-1:checked ~ label {
  background: lightgray;
}
#btn-1:checked ~ .container-fluid {
   background: #849D8F;
}
#btn-2:checked ~ label {
  background: red;
}
#btn-2:checked ~ .container-fluid {
   background: maroon;
}
#btn-3:checked ~ label {
  background: lightgreen;
}
#btn-3:checked ~ .container-fluid {
   background: green
}
```

```html
<div class='nav-bar'>
  <input type=radio id="btn-1" name="nav-bar-btn" checked />
  <input type=radio id="btn-2" name="nav-bar-btn"/>
  <input type=radio id="btn-3" name="nav-bar-btn"/>
  <label for="btn-1">#btn-1</label> 
  <label for="btn-2">#btn-2</label> 
  <label for="btn-3">#btn-3</label> 
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Я, наверное, неправильно выразился. Мне нужно меня цвет не кнопок слайдера, а элементов из навбара. То есть, структура на странице такая: хэдер, в котором меню и его элементы, а затем ниже идет слайдер со своими переключателями. Таким образом, мне нужно сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку переключения у слайдера - менялся бекграунд у элемента из меню, вооот.